# Cannot see GPT partitions

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, gpt

I recently did a byte copy (using `dd`) of my laptop HDD to an SSD and installed the SSD into the laptop. I had Windows and Ubuntu on the drive. There may not have been enough room to copy over the Ubuntu partition as that was corrupted in the process but Windows came across fine.

The `diskmgmt` utility in Windows shows all partitions of the GPT partitions but all partition actions (e.g. format and shrink) are disabled. Delete partition option is enabled but when trying to delete the Ubuntu / swap partitions I get the error "Incorrect parameter".

EaseUS Partition utility does not recognise the GPT partitions, it reports the drive is one Unassigned partition.

GRUB is not able to load linux, possibly because the kernel was not copied during the `dd`? Not sure why this would be as there are roughly 8Gb between the end of Ubuntu partition and the end of the disk.

Trying to load Ubuntu installer from USB results goes straight to GRUB, I cannot get it to load the installer.
Debian installer does load from USB but does not recognise the GPT partitions.

My aim is to reinstall Ubuntu but given the issues above I seem to be trapped.
Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: GPT comes with a secondary header that would now be missing. You should copy individual partitions of the destination drive is too small.

Comment: The backup header is unimportant (it's after all just a copy of the primary GPT which is in sector 1). But I'm guessing the system doesn't know where _sector 1_ is. **Did you copy between a 4k sector disk and a 512b sector disk?** And do Linux tools like `fdisk` or `gdisk` recognize the GPT?

Comment: `dd` is not a good tool for disk cloning because it does a byte copy which is slow and will cause problem if the target is smaller than the original disk as you see. A good cloning tool will smartly skip blank clusters and can shrink the volume if needed

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc `dd` is in no way slow. If properly used (`bs`) it is at fast as it gets.

Comment: @DanielB regardless of options it always does a byte-by-byte copy, so it'll copy zero clusters and clusters that are unused.

Comment: @grawity I am not aware of if I copied between 4k and 512 byte sector disk, SSHD is Seagate ST500LM000 if there is a relationship. Also `gdisk` finds nine partitions and reports: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT.

Answer (score 0):

With great powers comes great responsibility, and so `dd` should be avoided when possible (by default it's [slow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144172/full-dd-copy-from-hdd-to-hdd) and mess up [Unique IDs](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1680929&page=2#post10425340)). Had you used tools such as Clonezilla, they would have told you needed to resize and move partitions before proceeding.

Now you very likely have a screwed up partition table, with not only a "cut" partition (which is not all that much of a deal to fix) but a missing one too.

I think `gdisk` [should](https://askubuntu.com/a/386802/536967) be able to help you.